Why does my DC motor make whining noises when I try to drive it with a motor driver?
I want to drive this motor with this driver in a microcontroller project, but all I get is a loud whiny noise so I did some investigations and pinpointed my issue down to the driver.
My current (simplified) setup is this:

Please refer to the provided links to get more detailed descriptions on the DRV8833 module or on the motor.
I have two clean and separated 5V supplies and GND is shared on the modules board. Note that the DRV8833 module has also current limit features (AISEN, BISEN), but these are not active by default as stated by Pololu. In fact both, AISEN and BISEN are at 0V, and therefore no current limit should be active.
When I drive the motor directly with 5V, it all works fine. When driving the motor with the driver, it does nothing but make loud noises. When I drive another motor with higher voltage and less current, it also works.
I'm out of ideas and would be glad if someone could give me a hint what to investigate next.
Edit:
Here is an oscilloscope measurement of AOUT1 with a 1:100 probe head:

Edit 2:
More things I found out:

Driving another motor yields a constant output voltage at xOUT1/2.
Driving the peristaltic pump with 6V works. Reducing VIN to 5V gets me back to whining and oscillating output.

Edit 3:
Here is an oscilloscope measurement of VIN with a 1:100 probe head:


Are you able to use an oscilloscope to monitor the AOUT1 and AOUT2 pins of the DRV8833 when the problem occurs? That is try and identify if the DRV8833 is operating in current chopping mode.

@ChesterGillon Thank you for your comment. I've added the oscilloscope measurement in the question. I would expect it to be constant. But I'm not an electronics expert and cannot tell what it should look like

What does the Vin waveform look like during wining?

@winny Thanks, I've added the VIN waveform

That doesn't look like a solid 5 volt input. What are you using as a source for that input?

@MathKeepsMeBusy I have chosen a cheap dc power supply from amazon that I use, that delivers up to 30V and 5A. I tried it with different power sources too. USB port, phone power supply, 5V dc regulator. They all showed a similar VIN. When I do 6V, it all works as expected.

Looks like your input is drooping and the driver hits UVLO. Fix that first.

@winny This sounds reasonable. I checked for UVLO conditions mentioned in the datasheet of the DRV8833, but was unable to measure voltages below 2.5V on VM. Do you have an Idea what I could take as a power source?

If not this IC, does anything else in your circuit depend on 5 V? Does that part have UVLO?

@winny nothing I am aware of. It's just the schematic I posted in the question, nothing else. As a workaround I will continue searching for proper 6V regulators for now and investigate further with other 5V sources.

I see. Try a power supply with more peak current capability and preferably a big electrolytic capacitor on the supply pins of the module.
